# docker non-root bind-mount permissions, WITH --userns-remap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

all: flailing around trying to get bind-mount permissions working.

My goal is to bind mount a volume in a container, so that:

- (a) the container does NOT run the entry point as root user
- (b) the
  docker-daemon is configured with --userns-remap, so that container
  doesn't have root on the host
- (c) I can bind-mount and read/write a
  volume read-writable by my ordinary user (UID:GID 1000 on the host )
  using a container
- (d) when the files are created, they all have
  permissions as my regular host user, not root or nobody.

From a security perspective, we want to avoid containers having root on the host-- that's kind of a no-brainer -- that's requirement (b). Requirements a,c,and d come from the desire to send container logs to a bind-mounted dir on the filesystem, so they can be digested by splunk.  This configuration is/will be the preferred way to do logging on kubernetes ( see  [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24677) for more detail on that ).

Does anyone have a way to get all 4 of the requirements above?

Here is the easiest way to see the problem. Run Docker with --userns-remap:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--userns-remap=1000:1000"
```

Start container alpine, run it as root. Observe permissions on foo.txt are nobody. I expec them to be either root or 1000:1000 since thats what they are on the filesystem:

```
dcowden@ubuntu:~/gitwork/file-perm-stuff$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/dcowden/gitwork/file-perm-stuff/testlogs:/logs alpine /bin/sh
/ # ls -ln /logs
total 0
-rw-rw-r--    1 65534    65534            0 Aug 20 19:08 foo.txt
/ # exit
```

Exit container, and look at files. observe they are 1000:1000 owned, so userns remap has screwed them up:

```
dcowden@ubuntu:~/gitwork/file-perm-stuff$ ls -ln testlogs
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Aug 20 15:08 foo.txt
dcowden@ubuntu:~/gitwork/file-perm-stuff$ ls -ln .
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  248 Aug 20 16:07 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Aug 20 16:09 testlogs
```

A more sophisticated Dockerfile, trying to create a non-priveliged container user also fails, though that's pretty clear since it already doesnt work with root.  It is not as complex as the dynamic solution from [2](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/), but it still fails :

```bash
FROM alpine:3.4
    
ENV USER_ID=1000
ENV USER_NAME="appuser"
RUN addgroup -g $USER_ID -S $USER_NAME
RUN adduser -u $USER_ID -S -G $USER_NAME $USER_NAME

RUN mkdir /logs && chown $USER_NAME:$USER_NAME /logs

VOLUME /logs
WORKDIR /logs
USER $USER_NAME
```

I am aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291520/docker-and-userns-remap-how-to-manage-volume-permissions-to-share-data-betwee), but it doesn't provide an answer. In fact, simply using --userns-remap=1000:1000 produces a suitable /etc/subuid configuration without any manual edits required, but still does not work with the bind mount.

I am also aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140911/can-i-control-the-owner-of-a-bind-mounted-volume-in-a-docker-image), and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146818/issue-when-trying-to-write-to-a-mounted-volume-from-inside-a-container-as-a-non) but i appear to have matched the userids as both suggest, without a suitable result.

I followed the instructions [here](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/), and I achieved a setup that meets all requirements except (b) above-- that it, it works great when i'm not using userns-remap

When I add this line to DOCKER_OPTS ( enabling userns-remap):

--userns-remap=1000:1000

Then the whole thing stops working, and nothing I do seems to work. The bind-mounted volume appears to be owned by nobody. I've tried the following things, none of which have any affect:

1. add Z option to the end of the volume mapping
2. run this command in the host:  'chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /path/to/volume' ( from [here](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/)

My guess is that something is going wrong due to the fact that i'm simultaneously telling docker to map the container root user to my UID (1000), and ALSO creating another user with that same UID:GUID explicitly.  That *should* be fine-- in the container, root is 0:0, and I create UID:GUI 1000:1000 also. when files are created, both root and non-root should create files with ownership 1000:1000.  When running the image as both non-root and root, this is in fact the case.

It's just that everything fails when trying to write to a bind-mounted volume.

Here's my setup:

Docker 1.12
Ubuntu 14.04
Unprivileged UID:GID on host: 1000:1000

Docker info:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 41
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 25
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host null bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-83-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 7.785 GiB
Name: ubuntu
ID: 2OO6:ESDJ:WGQ2:UGEQ:5ULF:MXNY:E5XC:WWWN:KJGJ:X2GT:I6VV:V2DN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/100000.100000
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: dcowden
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: curious if you are still looking on getting logs to splunk from kubernetes, we have build a ready to use applications for monitoring kubernetes (metrics and logs forwarding), you can find more details on https://www.outcoldsolutions.com
FYI: I am original author of Splunk Logging Driver and original Splunk Docker Images.